# String is inserted with additional '?' in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, string, powershell

I'm using Exchange Web Services to get the text from an email and add it to a database. So I start like this:

```
$PropertySet = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet(
    [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties);
$PropertySet.RequestedBodyType = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BodyType]::Text;

$email_obj = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage]::Bind($service,$itemID);
$email_obj.Load($PropertySet);

#getting rid of replies
$Message = $email_obj.Body.Text -replace '\s+', ' '
if($Message -like "* From: *"){
    $Message = ($Message -split " From: ")[0]
}
if($Message.IndexOf('_') -ne (-1)){
    $Message = $Message.Remove($Message.IndexOf('_'))
}
```

Then, I insert the email body in SQL Server:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO DB.Table ([ID],[Message],[Sender],[Recipient],[TimeStamp])
     VALUES ($ID,'$Message','$Sender','$Recipient',{0})" -f (Get-TimeStamp)
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -ServerInstance $server
```

But the `INSERT` adds `?` in front of the string that is the message. Tried to format the string before doing the `INSERT` but it didn't help. Can't find any hidden characters like `\n`,`\r`,`\t` or `\s`.
Only the string that I get from the body of the email produces this result.

Comment: do a per-char hex value dump of the string. `?` could just mean "unknown character"

Comment: Likely your Message string is in UTF-8 and the database field is not (varchar instead of nvarchar).

Comment: My money's on you have Unicode data in the string but your column is varchar (as @TonPlooij suggested). Funny I just blogged about this today: http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-unicode/

Comment: @MarcB for some reason the string `something` it does it well. But for most string, like `asdfg` the hex value dump produces `E2808B6173646667200D0A`. So the culprit is `E` that's `Shift Out` character.
@TonPlooij and @AaronBertrand the SQL variable is nvarchar.

@All adding `N` before the string when inserting made the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution has to do with the data format, like everyone said. The column is `nvarchar` and don't know exactly what data format was the string that I was trying to insert, but it had 1 or more `unknown characters` sometimes. To solve this, just added `N` prefix while doing `INSERT` in the table, like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO DB.Table ([ID],[Message],[Sender],[Recipient],[TimeStamp])
                  VALUES ($ID,N'$Message','$Sender','$Recipient',{0})" -f (Get-TimeStamp)
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -ServerInstance $server
```

[This article](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-unicode/) from @AaronBertrand explains data formats in SQL.